# Можно ли встроить изображение в кнопку в телеграмм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Меня интересует можно ли как-нибудь запихнуть изображение помимо стандартных эмодзи телеграмма в кнопку или это просто невозможно сделать.

[image: Это стандартный эмодзи телеграмма, а нужно фото из файла.]

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в подобные кнопки картинку невозможно, т.к. они [не содержат](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) специального поля для изображений, а имеют лишь текстовое поле.

Но как вы правильно указали, можно использовать **юникодовские эмодзи**.

Если вам нужны именно картинки, можете использовать [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), а именно параметр `switch_inline_query_current_chat`, в него можно добавить специфичную информацию, состоящую из текста и картинки.

Comment: Я не говорил что кнопка должна быть именно KeyboardButton и предполагал  что она будет  InlineKeyboardButton, а вот за параметр спасибо обязательно попробую.

Comment: @SL_ На скриншоте у вас именно `KeyboardButton`.